# How to support pronouns within Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm creating an Alexa skill with intents that supports, amongst others, the following utterances:

> What lessons does {Mabel} have tomorrow?
>
> Does {Mabel} have any homework?

where "Mabel" is a slot of type AMAZON.GB_FIRST_NAME.

In order to make the skill more conversational, I'd like to support the following:

> What lessons does {Mabel} have tomorrow?
>
> Does {she} have any homework?

where "she" is a custom slot that represents Pronoun.

This would require the response to the first question to store Mabel's Id in the session attributes so that when the user subsequently uses a pronoun, the skill could determine the subject of the question.

In theory, this should work.  However, because the student-name and the pronoun slot are in the same position within the utterance, Alexa reports "she" as the name; the pronoun slot is never used or resolved.

Therefore, my question is, how can I encourage the pronoun-slot resolution without changing the utterance structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional slot values to the AMAZON.GB_FIRST_NAME built-in slot ("he", "she", etc) and do the pronoun detection and resolution yourself as you described.  This will avoid the need for a new slot type.